# grid creation using canvas in tkinter and oop

Tags: python, tkinter

Please forgive my programming skills(m a newbie).Need to prepare a grid of rectangles inside a canvas boxes using oop approach,using only one class. But unable to decide about the defination of the initialisation and method.

Suppose that I have a root as the base window. I created a canvas inside this root.Inside this canvas I need to have a grid of rectangles, the position of these rectangles should be user selective(the function to create rectangles in user defined way has been worked out so no problem with respect to it). The hierarchy goes like this.....root-->Canvas(H1)--->Machines(M1)These rectangles need to be acessed later using the parent canvas(not the root but canvas in which they are embedded-H1).My problem is to access these rectangles using the canvas.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import font
from tkinter import *
import time

root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1860x820")

h=690
w=220

class Halls():
        def __init__(self,hallname,**kwarg):
                self.hallname=tk.Canvas(root,height=h,width=w)
                self.hallname.place(x=100,y=200)


        def machinecreation(self,machinename):
                self.machinename=self.hallname.create_rectangle
                                                   (20,20,40,40)

H1=Halls('H1')
H1.machinecreation('M1')

H1.M1()

root.update()
```

It gives an attribute error, Halls does not have attribute machinename. Its basically error related to python and not tkinter. The code i mentioned is a basic one. Many halls(canvases) and machines(rectangle) will be added. Basically its like trying to create a Canvas object(Hall) and then accessing a method.

Comment: Actually you can access the `machine` by `H1.machinename`.

Comment: Thanks @acw1668 for your reply. However I have many machines,which I need to access by their respective names., something like 'H1,A1', 'H1.A2' or for a different canvas 'H2.A1', 'H2.A2' and so on....

Comment: Then you need to define a dictionary in `Halls` class to hold the machines using `machinename` as key.  Also you need to define a function `get(machinename)` in `Halls` class to return the machine with the given `machinename`, like `H1.get('M1')`.